# Eclipse error, "Could not find or load main class test.Main"

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, classpath

There are many questions like this, but I've tried everything in the answers to all of them on this site and nothing has worked so far.

I am using `Eclipse` and am trying to launch the following `Main.java` within the folder `test` using `Ctrl+F11`:

```
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

I get the following error: `Error: Could not find or load main class test.Main`.

Here is my `.classpath` file. ***Note this is not an issue with this file*** (or at least it is not solely due to this file), since I have created a new project called `MainProject2` with the same `Main` file, and I copied the following `.classpath` into `MainProject2`, which ***does not*** break that project's main files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="src/" kind="src" path=""/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ProjA"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ProjB"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ProjC"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/myusername/workspace/ProjE/lib/guava-16.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/myusername/workspace/ProjD/lib/commons-collections4-4.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/myusername/workspace/ProjD/lib/commons-configuration-1.9.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/myusername/workspace/ProjD/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/myusername/workspace/ProjD/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/myusername/workspace/ProjD/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/myusername/workspace/ProjD/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" exported="true" kind="src" path="/ProjF"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/ProjD"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Under my `Run Configurations -> ClassPath -> User Entries`, it will show `MainProject (default classpath)` (nb: the project's name is `MainProject` so that should be correct). I am using `JavaSE-1.7` which I use for every project. The `Main` tab within `Run Configurations` seems correct. It says `Project: MainProject`, `Main Class: test.Main`. All three checkboxes are unchecked in here.

The project is a `Java` project and has the `J` above it in the Package Explorer. I have checked it out from `SVN` (I am the one that uploaded it and running main methods used to work).

I have tried cleaning and refreshing the project, restarting Eclipse, deleting and recreating `Main.java` and nothing has worked yet. I have also attempted manually doing `Run As -> Run As Java Application`, which doesn't work. I have also tried this same class under a different name to `Main.java` (e.g. `RandomTest.java`). I have also tried deleting the project from workspace and re-importing it. In addition, it is not a fundamental problem with my `Eclipse` since I can create a new project with the same `Main` (as the only `.java` file in the project) and it will compile without issue.

I have also tried the following from CMD:

```
user@place:~$ javac /home/user/workspace/MainProject/src/test/Main.java
user@place:~$ java /home/user/workspace/MainProject/src/test/Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /home/user/workspace/MainProject/src/test/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .home.user.workspace.MainProject.src.test.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: /home/user/workspace/MainProject/src/test/Main. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Have you run the class using cmd line ??

Comment: Try right click inside the editor, Run as java app. Not from run configuratins.

Comment: This looks extremely suspicious: `<classpathentry excluding="src/" kind="src" path=""/>`. Try removing it.

Comment: @ThrashBean Doesn't work

Comment: @NiksTyagi Didn't work (see edited post)

Comment: @user2763361: your command line attempt didn't work because your java command is incorrect. It should be `java -cp /home/user/workspace/MainProject/src test.Main` (assuming you have Main.class under /home/user/workspace/MainProject/src/test)

Comment: @user2763361 do you find .class file for Main class at location /home/user/workspace/MainProject/src/test ??

Comment: @NiksTyagi Yes a `Main.class` (419 bytes) was created after I followed your instruction.

Comment: Try doing a clean build.

Comment: @JBNizet `java -cp /home/user/...` doesn't work, it just gives me options. `Usage: java [-options] class [args...]` followed by a spam in my console of various option settings ended by `See http://java.sun.com/javase/reference for more details.
`

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati Do you mean creating a new Java Project and moving all `.java` files over? (I googled the terminology `clean build` and wasn't able to find a precise meaning). I have clicked `Project -> Clean -> MainProject` many times.

Comment: Try to clean all the projects. For the commandline execution - you should execute from bin (up to your .classpath definition)

Comment: @ThrashBean I created a second project `MainProject2` with the exact same `.classpath` file, identical `Build Path` settings, identical `Run Configurations`, identical dependencies on other projects, and it works perfectly fine. So I don't think that cleaning the other projects will do anything since this second project that I made has identical dependencies on those projects but functions well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the directory in which the `Main` class exist.Then compile it as below :

compile using the `-d` option so that the classes end up in an appropriate directory hierarchy:

```
javac -d . Main.java
```

Then run the class using below command :

```
java test.Main
```

Comment: If I do this I now get the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`, I think this command is trying to use the the incorrect jdk version (1.6/1.7)?

Comment: @user2763361 you are using different version of java during compiling and running the java code ??

Comment: @user2763361 What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

First classpathentry should be like this

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
```

after change this, you may have to clean this project and restart your eclipse.

If this works, there should be a test/Main.class file in your bin folder

Comment: Doesn't work. In addition, I use the same `.classpath` as you see in the post in a dummy project I set up called `MainProject2`, which has only the `Hello World` program. In this project, the program will compile and run perfectly well. It is only in my big project that it doesn't work. Note that all other settings seem to be the same in this second project as well.

Comment: for your eclipse, there should be a class file located in /home/user/workspace/MainProject/bin/test/Main.class

You cd into  "/home/user/workspace/MainProject/bin/" and run
    "java test.Main".
If it works, your eclipse should be ok.

But, is there the class file?